# Platform specific View/Page implementation in .net MAUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui

I'm trying to migrate the application implemented using xamarin form and xamarin native.

For example application has four screens out of it two screens(screen1,screen2) implemented using xamarin.form and other two(screen3, screen4) using xamarin native(xamarin.android and xamarin.ios).

Now while migration able to migrate screen1 and screen2(Form) but facing challenges with screen3 and 4(Native).

Can we use the existing screens implemented using storyboard for iOS and xml layout for Android.
As of now storyboard initialization using
`Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(..) as myViewController` returns null.

Even getting resource path from bundle returns null

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(..)
```

For storyboard not able to set build action to InterfaceDefinition under maui project as this option not available inside Platforms iOS folder.

How can we add new Storyboard/Viewcontroller class to Platform/iOS ?

Any hints/example link for similar project migration will be helpful.

**Update:**

Recreating both viewcontroller and storyboard and moving to root directory with root namespace worked intialisation.
Still facing some tableviewcell unknown key exception

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code). It tells `Invoke platform code` in details.

Comment: This one i already implemented. i'm looking for migration of screen implemented using  using xamarin native(ex : iOS story board ).

Comment: @Suchith have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/

Comment: @Saamer Not looking for native view implementation in Form. Native views which are already implemented using storyboard need to migrate to MAUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the code in the file named "LaunchScreen.storyboard" in the xamarin.ios project. Then create a xml file named "LaunchScreen.storyboard" in Platform\ios folder in the .net MAUI project, and Paste the code you copied into it.

Comment: still facing the issue listed in the question. storyboard typecasting throwing error and NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource returns null. Created sample app here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0C2pKZYg1m7WFcy1zQF0GHDOKKN2sLJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Suchith Could you upload the code to GitHub, I can't see the code from the link you provide. :(

Comment: Viewcontroller initialization working after moving storyboard and viewcontroller to root directory

Comment: @Suchith I am in the process of migrating a Xamarin.iOS storyboard and associated view controller to MAUI ,it would be great if you could share a sample app, how you do it for your project

Comment: @RaGibNoor What issue you are facing ?

Comment: I have started the migration, if you could share the sample app I might use it as a reference